# Fusionemos las etiquetas [dynamics-crmy] y [dynamics-crm-2011]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Las etiquetas [dynamics-crm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) y [dynamics-crm-2011](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-2011) deberían ser funcionadas, quizá quedando como [dynamics-crm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm).

Ambas etiquetas hacen referencia al programa de Microsoft, la propuesta, de manera genérica, y la otra a una versión en concreto. Aunque pienso que sería mejor dejarlas con la genérica

Comment: Apenas se han utilizado una vez, por lo que el proceso es tan fácil como eliminar una de [la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103338/83) donde están.

Comment: Esperemos a ver que piensan otros sobre esto. Si se decide que sería mejor tener una solamente ¡con gusto lo hacemos!